# How to set security policy on Azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-policy

I have two teams:

- Team1: Who supports the subscription (having Storage1) and having the contributor access
- Team2: Who owns the subscription (having Storage1) and has the contributor access.

The storage (storage1) has data which Team2 (owner) don't want to show the data to Team1 (support team).

Considering the above scenario, is there any **security policy** at the **storage level** put in place so that [even if the Support team(Team1) has contributor access to the subscription] can NOT view the data from the storage?

Please suggest the best ways to proceed forward.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are specific data action permissions that allow crud operations for blobs. If `Team2` does not have those permissions they'll not be able to do anything with the blobs. One of the built-in roles with those permissions is the `Storage Blob Data Contributor`, while resource roles such as `Contributor` or `Storage Account Contributor` don't have those.

**However**; the default `Contributor` and `Storage Blob Data Contributor` roles give access to the access keys, which can also be used to gain access to the blobs. You could disable access keys, but a contributor has access to that option and could enable them again.

So if you want to limit your contributors you can do so; but you'll require a different role (likely a custom role) that does not have access to the `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listkeys/action` permission.